# Discord Bot Created Overlay Ready Check - Is it possible?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Can I create/add a bot to my discord server that adds functions to the overlay that would allow me to add a button "Ready" / "Not Ready" for those on a specific call.

I already have a discord bot running and working, but was unsure if:
1 - can bots interact with an overlay?
2 - can the overlay have clickable buttons?

After some research, i think the answer is no, but I wanted to see if anyone had any clues.